# How to counter the "ugliness" of Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a very large QToolButton with an icon and text under each other.

Instead of it being displayed like this:

```
|-------------|
|             |
|             |
|             |
|   <image>   |
|    text     |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|-------------|
```

it is displayed like this:

```
|-------------|
|   <image>   |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|    text     |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|-------------|
```

Is there a way to center them both vertically together, besides creating a custom layout for it and adding the image, text and `QSpacerItem`s manually?

The following result would be suboptimal, but still much better than the original:

```
|-------------|
|             |
|             |
|   <image>   |
|             |
|             |
|    text     |
|             |
|             |
|-------------|
```

Comment: Put in some newlines before <image> (sorry bout that)

Comment: @SebastianLange : I just found ASCII art to be quicker than creating, editing and submitting screenshots.

Comment: have you tried using stylesheets? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbutton